# How to implement angular resolver using function?

Tags: angular, resolver, angular-resolver

I want to create a data resolver for my nav-bar. So using service I can't put it into my app-routing module because of nav-bar components not in the routing module. How to fix it?

If it's duplicated, feel free to close this question, but I didn't find the answer after googling, stack overflowing and in the related topics.

Thanks for your help!